# What is the correct definition of "étale cover"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

In many books, an étale covering (used for defining étale fundamental group) of a scheme $X$ is defined as $f:Y\rightarrow X$, where $f$ is a finite étale morphism.

In some other books, $f$ should be a *surjective* finite étale morphisms.

Why do we have two different definitions?

Answer (score 5):

The better definition is the one that does **not** require that an étale cover be surjective.
Here are some reasons:

1) The original definition in [SGA 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206203) (Définition 4.9,page 5) by Grothendieck and his students does not require étale covers to be surjective.
2) Occam's razor: do not introduce extraneous conditions which don't seem to serve any purpose.
3) Étale covers in algebraic geometry are to be analogues of finite covers in topology.
But coverings in topology shouldn't be assumed surjective : this is for example  Bourbaki's point of view in his [new volume on Algebraic Topology](http://www.springer.com/fr/book/9783662493601) (see page 68).
     4) [Here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj4qcaNvsTTAhUMbxQKHfynBxYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.renyi.hu%2F~szamuely%2FCLSz.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFRmXafV34yzfEtBRNi6_v9IAQKYQ&sig2=fUfa6wTCbNcLSD03FRi6Rw) at the end of page 2 is Chambert-Loir's argument, expressed in the most elevated form of French poetry, the [alexandrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrine).
The lamentably prosaic rendition of his argument is that requiring surjectivity would destroy the category equivalence between étale covers and  $\pi_1$-sets.
Chambert-Loir diplomatically describes the incorporation of surjectivity in the definition of étale covers as "étrange", which means "strange".

Comment: Cover or covering means in english, or its translations, an object lying over fully a given one, so the concept contains the idea of surjectivity. I can see why you would want to consider maps which are not surjective but why not call them just maps instead of covers?

Comment: @plm Because étale covers are very, very special maps

Comment: yes and why not use "étale morphism" for a map like $x\mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb A^1$ and "etale cover" $x\mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}$ (over $\mathbb C$) to $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}$? That is, use cover when it's surjective only? It would avoid assumptions which look unjustified to novice (and which are only justified mysteriously and slightly poetically when asking experts). Also topological covering spaces are assumed surjective.

Comment: @plm No, contrary to what you wrongly claim many excellent topologists  (Bourbaki, Hatcher,...)  do no assume that a covering space is surjective: Hatcher  for example  explicitly writes on page 56  of his [book](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) that the projection map of a covering space need not be surjective.

Comment: It s strange, I can find the definition of a covering in Hatcher's book, and it does require surjectivity: "A covering space of a space X is a space X' together with a map p : X'→X satisfying the following condition: Each point x ∈ X has an open neighborhood U in X such that p−1(U) is a union". Since a neighborhood is nonempty (contains x) and $p^{-1}(U)$ is mapped onto it, the map surjective. But I just find your reply strange, I mean, I am thinking I must miss a point but I find all this confusing. Sorry if I miss some obvious point.

Comment: @plm: 1) The text you pretend to quote has been substantially changed by you. This is a dishonest procedure: whatever stands between quotation marks must be the author's text  *verbatim*   2) In **the very next sentence** Hatcher writes explicitly:  "We do not require $p^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ to be nonempty , so  $p$ need not be surjective." So you misquote an author, refuse to acknowledge  that he wrote exactly what I claimed: that $p$ needn't be surjective,  and you have the cheek to find my "reply strange"!  I've had enough of this sterile exhange and my interaction with you ends here and now.

Comment: I copy/pasted the text from Hatcher, I am not so hard-working as to actually temper with his text. Sorry that I did not read the continuation of that paragraph in Hatcher's book. You are right that he then says that he does not require $p$ to be surjective. But then this is in contradiction with the former part of his definition. I still find all this confusing and I am sorry I upset you but I am still pretty sure that if you ask mathematicians over half of them will tell you a covering space has a surjective projection. SIncerely.

Comment: @plm It is not contradictory. A union could be empty (coproduct over empty index), and the assertion is vacuously true.

Comment: I don't know whether my understanding is correct: étale covers correpond to locally constant finite étale sheaves (aka. local systems), while étale algebraic spaces correspond to étale sheaves, not necessarily locally constant, which makes étale covers special?